# How to add dynamically C function in embedded Python

Tags: python, c, function

I declare a C function as Python prototype

```
static PyObject* MyFunction(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
    return Py_None ;
}
```

Now I want to add it into a dynamically loaded module

```
PyObject *pymod = PyImport_ImportModule("mymodule");
PyObject_SetAttrString( pymod, "myfunction", ? );
```

How to convert C function into PyObject callable ?

Comment: Which version of python?

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to construct a new `PyCFunctionObject` object from the `MyFunction`. Usually this is done under the hood using the module initialization code, but as you're now doing it the opposite way, you need to construct the `PyCFunctionObject` yourself, using the undocumented `PyCFunction_New` or `PyCFunction_NewEx`, and a suitable [`PyMethodDef`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/structures.html#c.PyMethodDef):

```
static PyMethodDef myfunction_def = { 
    "myfunction", 
    MyFunction,
    METH_VARARGS,
    "the doc string for myfunction"
};

... 

    // Use PyUnicode_FromString in Python 3.
    PyObject* module_name = PyString_FromString("mymodule");
    if (module_name == NULL) {
        // error exit!
    }

    // this is adapted from code in code in 
    // Objects/moduleobject.c, for Python 3.3+ and perhaps 2.7
    PyObject *func = PyCFunction_NewEx(&myfunction_def, pymod, module_name);
    if (func == NULL) {
        // error exit!
    }
    if (PyObject_SetAttrString(module, myfunction_def.ml_name, func) != 0) {
        Py_DECREF(func);
        // error exit!
    }
    Py_DECREF(func);
```

Again, this is not the preferred way to do things; usually a C extension creates concrete module objects (such as `_mymodule`) and `mymodule.py` would import `_mymodule` and put things into proper places.

Comment: Was there NewEx in Python 2?

Comment: Yes in methodobject.h